# Get feature image from REST API wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I use Reactjs to fetch `feature post image` of Wordpress by `REST API` with code above but it appears an error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

```
<img className="coho" src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url} />
```

While `post.title.rendered` returns exactly.

Can you explain what wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use below api will work :

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed
```

and you will receive parameters as below :

```
"feature_image": "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/test-300x225.jpg",
"feature_full_image": "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/test-app-400.jpg",
```

then just use below code will work :

```
post.feature_image
post.feature_full_image
```

Tested and works perfect.